# Go to command prompt when computer tuns out of memory

Tags: ram, reboot

Is there a way to fall back to command line in Ubuntu 18.04 when computer runs out of memory?

It used to be Alt+F2 (and I was able to kill consuming processes), now I can only do REISUB or restart.

[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: Not really, the kernel's `oom_killer` doesn't have preferences. Have you considered swap space or a swap file?

Comment: I have a swap, but each time RAM is full, it freezes.

Comment: What does `free` show? Is your swap space in use?

Comment: Swap is in use, cna't say precisely since when that happens, I can't open any app.